# Google+ iphone app with hangouts, how to implement a hangout feature yourself?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-plus, google-hangouts

Since short time ago, Google + has had hangouts implemented on the iPhone. You can chat and stream video like Skype.

I have searched online for a way to implement a hangout feature where you can chat and stream like Skype.

Does it use Facetime API ? Or is there a way to implement such a feature?

Who knows if and how this can be done.  I'm looking for some general advice on which iPhone libraries to use to achieve same functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hangouts API](http://developers.google.com/+/hangouts) provides you the capability to write JavaScript / HTML applications which run inside hangouts as viewed from desktop web browsers.  It does not provide any capability to write apps for mobile hangouts at this time.